# Python list comprehension syntax showing output expression as "optional"?

Tags: python, syntax, list-comprehension

This following page [see below] has a syntax description for a Python list comprehension which says that the output expression is "Optional."  I haven't seen this "optional" designation elsewhere and it doesn't seem that a list comprehension would work without it.   EG.

```
>>> llist = [1, 2, 3] 

# list comprehension with output expression works
>>> listc = [num for num in llist]

# list comprehension without output expression fails
>>> listc2 =[for num in llist]
   File "<stdin>", line 1
listc2 =[for num in llist]
               ^
   SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

** Here is the page:** 
https://python-reference.readthedocs.io/en/latest/docs/comprehensions/list_comprehension.html
and here is the description from that page:

```
[expression(variable) for variable in input_set [predicate][, …]]

expression
Optional. An output expression producing members of the new set from members of the input set that satisfy the predicate expression.

variable
Required. Variable representing members of an input set.

input_set
Required. Represents the input set.

predicate
Optional. Expression acting as a filter on members of the input set.

[, …]]
Optional. Another nested comprehension.
```

**Possibly** they are trying to say that you can start a list comprehension with a bare variable, but that is still an expression, correct?

Comment: expression refers to some function on variable, i.e `num*2` for example

Comment: Yeah, this isn't very clear or good documentation. `expression(variable)` already doesn't make sense, because that's *specifically* function-call syntax. It's true that `function(variable)` and `(variable)` would both work, but that's under-selling it :)

Comment: The front page of this documentation indicates a copyright date of 2015 and "DRAFT" status, so I'm guessing the author gave up on it....

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : good catch, which made me wonder how I came across it.  The answer/problem is that, for some reason, when one does a Google search for
**python set comprehension** 
  (I may have tried "set..." first) **the #1 hit on Google** is the same site's corresponding "Set comprehension" page, with the same "expression . Optional" first element.   So, I decided that I should ask about it. :)  This is not helped by the fact that there are *many* variations of syntax for these comprehensions; I can't find a definitive version, or even a consistent one.   Any idea where I should look? Thx

Comment: If you want *authoritative* and *correct*, and ease of understanding doesn't matter so much (although there *is* a tutorial section), start with docs.python.org :)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : I can get the ease of understanding from multiple sources, or at least from combining what I read from multiple sources.  However, when I still have a specific question after that, it's nice to be able to have an authoritative spot to go to.  Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the doc is a bit unclear. You do need *something* on the left hand side. Otherwise the comprehension doesn't make much sense.

Comment: thanks.  I'm obviously new to Python, so I wanted a second (or more) opinion.

Answer (score 1):

The page you have linked in an unofficial reference for Python, and as you can see on the [GitHub page](https://github.com/jprzywoski/python-reference), it hasn't been updated in about 4 years. If you would like the up to date, and more importantly, correct information, go to the [official documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/)

Here is the link relevent to list comprehensions and their syntax
https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

> A list comprehension consists of brackets containing an expression
>   followed by a for clause, then zero or more for or if clauses.

Answer (score 0):

The page you mentioned is quite clear about the `expression`. It's true, that in `[expression(variable) for variable in input_set [predicate][, …]]` the `expression` is optional, you may leave the `variable` as is, and it will still work. Moreover, you may leave there anything you like, not even remotely connected to the `variable`, like a number `42`, and it still works.

Probably the original intention of the authors of the original page was to explain that you don't have to do anything with the loop variable if you don't want to an leave it `as is`.